# Efficient way to check table layout and update if necessary

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

I'm currently building a plugin for a game, and I'm using SQLite (though, I need the solution to work with MySQL too). I've already released one version but my new version requires a table change.

What's the most efficient way in Java to check if all the columns in a table exist, and if they don't update the table without losing the data?

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the tables on the first run of the new version, or do something like

```
try {
  readData();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  // if the cause is missing new columns
  alterTables();
  readData();
}
```

There are many other solutions possible.

Comment: Perhaps make a `String` array containing the names of the columns in your tables and then loop through them all with `ResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(int)`, then do as @jlordo suggests.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart) to create / migrate the data after each version. Liquibase allows you to create the change based on a config file (.xml) and then later, if you add more change to the config file, it will automatically update the old database for you